# Getting null in httpResponseMessage when calling REST API using HTTPClient

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to execute a REST API which uses HTTP POST. The API consumes and produces xml content. I am getting null in httpResponseMessage and no exception is thrown. I tried executing the same REST API through HttpWebRequest I am getting the response Below you can find Working and Not Working case. Performance wise HttpWebRequest or HTTPClient which is better ?

**Not Working case HTTPClient**

```
try {
    using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
        Console.WriteLine(inputxml);

        var httpContent = new StringContent(inputxml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

        Uri testUri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/services/getDocument");

        var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(testUri, httpContent);

        Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            var messageContents = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }

}
```

**Working Case HTTPWebREquest**

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/services/getDocument");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputxml.ToString());
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response;
response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine("responseStr " + responseStr);
    return responseStr;
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: If the StatusCode is not 200 OK then what is it? Also did you look at the ReasonPhrase?

Comment: I am not able to check what is the StatusCode and ReasonPhrase the program is getting terminated once the  var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(testUri, httpContent); gets null value.

Comment: For repoducing the issue , please share your Rest Api Code.

Comment: if dev url is available that will be better

Comment: Thanks Biju. I do not have the REST API code and the API can be executed only within my network. As of now I am just using the HTTPWebRequest class and consuming the REST API which is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

You're reading the response body, and printing `System.Threading.Task`1` to the console. Then the next time you try to read the response body again, its stream is at its end and won't return anything.

Read the content once, await the call and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use RestSharp for sending HTTP Requests.
For me, the best and the simplest method for HTTP Communication.

```
public string SendRequest(String xml)
    {
        string responseMessage= "";
        RestClient restClient;
        restClient = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/services/getDocument");
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        restRequest.AddXmlBody(xml);
        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
        if (restResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            responseMessage= restResponse.Content;
        }
        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```